# Setting up a class with a specific parameter

Tags: java, class, parameters

Can anybody explain to me why this doesn't work and how I go about setting this class up to run with a specified parameter? (the intial balance) I wanted to run this class from my main program with a specific parameter passed as the initial balance. Do I need to setup start balance as a class variable?

```
public class LoanAccount
{
static float interestRate = 0.006F;
private float balance;

public LoanAccount(float StartBalance)
{
    balance = StartBalance;
}

public float getBalance(){
    return balance;
}

public void addInterest(){
    float interest = balance * interestRate;
    balance = balance + interest;
}

public void makePayment(float LPaid){
    balance = balance - LPaid;
}

public static void main(){
    LoanAccount BankLoan = new LoanAccount(StartBalance); 

}

}
```

Comment: What is Your Question?
Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this row:

```
LoanAccount BankLoan = new LoanAccount(StartBalance);
```

`StartBalance` is not defined. You need to supply an actual value to the constructor, or a float variable that has been initialized with a value.

Comment: Would I need to set it up as a class variable with an initial value then?

Comment: If you have it as a static class variable it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
LoanAccount BankLoan = new LoanAccount(StartBalance);
```

you just need

```
LoanAccount BankLoan = new LoanAccount(1500.0f);
```

or whatever balance you want to start out with.

Comment: I want it to be a changing value which can be inputted when the class is called

Comment: @Espore Then you need your value to come from somewhere! If you're going to be generating it programmatically, you get yourself some `float myBalance` somehow, and call it by passing `myBalance`. If you want to be able to specify the value on the command line when you run the application, then Eran's answer is the one to go for.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the StartBalance as a command line argument :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    float StartBalance = 0.0;
    try {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            StartBalance = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);
            LoanAccount BankLoan = new LoanAccount(StartBalance);
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
        System.out.println("invalid input : " + args[0]);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent initialised StartBalance, that you are meant to pass on to constructor while creating LoanAccount. You could do it in two ways like:

```
 LoanAccount BankLoan = new LoanAccount(10.0f);
```

Or you could define a local variable in the main method like:

```
float initialBalance = 10.0f;
LoanAccount BankLoan = new LoanAccount(initialBalance);
LoanAccount BankLoan2 = new LoanAccount(initialBalance);
```